# React Navigation params doesn't reset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm having trouble with resetting the navigation params to null in React Native.

MainTab
 -- Home (stack)
 -- Misc (stack)
 -- Tips (stack)

On the Home tab, I have a button to go to Misc, but I want to route to the Tips tab on route to Misc.
Routing should look like - (Home -> Tips -> Misc)
That button returns the following with params -

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate('Tips', {backRoute: 'Home', routeImGoingNext: 'Misc'});
```

When these params are passed, I render a back button and a skip button on the Tips screen's navigation based on the backRoute and routeImGoingNext params that were passed from the button on the Home tab.

```js
if(navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.backRoute){
  return {
    headerLeft: (<HeaderBackButton onPress={()=>navigation.navigate(navigation.state.params.backRoute)}/> ),
    headerRight: (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate(navigation.state.params.routeImGoingnext)}>
        <Text style={{paddingRight: 10}}> Skip </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}
```

My problem occurs when I click the Tips tab after I've already clicked the the button on the Home tab. The params are still set and therefore rendering a back button and skip button, but there shouldn't be those buttons if I click the Tips tab.

Any ideas on how to reset the params when you manually click on the tabs?

Answer (score 22):

I was able to clear the params by manually creating a function and setting the params that are passed to null. The clearParams function is called when the header button is pressed.

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {

  clearParams = () => {
    navigation.setParams({backRoute: null, routeImGoingNext: null})
  }

  if(navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.backRoute){  

    const { backRoute, routeImGoingNext } = navigation.state.params;

    return {
      headerLeft: (<HeaderBackButton onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate(backRoute), clearParams()}}/> ),
      headerRight: (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate(routeImGoingNext), clearParams() }}>
          <Text style={{paddingRight: 10}}> Skip </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    }
  }
 return;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't exactly work on web, on the other hand setting them to `undefined` instead does work.

Answer (score 15):

Use this for clear params in `react navigation`

```js
this.props.navigation.setParams({YOUR_PARAMS: null});
```

Answer (score 3):

I've also run into this issue and I found in documentation that params are shallow merged so if you have some prams from previous navigation and then you navigate to same screen with different params then they will be merged.
Here is a link to documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params
Quick example will be:

```
navigation.navigate('Receipt', {id: '001', eventId: 'eventIdMock');
```

and from another screen, if I navigate to Receipt with this params:

```
navigation.navigate('Receipt', {id: '002'});
```

then the navigation will still have `eventId: 'eventIdMock'`
so the solution is to set explicitly this value to `null` or `undefined`

```
navigation.navigate('Receipt', {id: '002', eventId: null});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, straight from the documentation. Note that this resets the entire navigation state (props/routes/params etc...). In my case this was fine.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/

```
    props.navigation.reset({
        index: 0,
        routes: [{name: "Screen you need to go back to"}]
    });
```

My app is a simple 3 screen app in react native using react navigation "bottom tab navigator". All of my components are functional components so I did not use any sort of navigation-actions from this section of the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions.

See my stack-navigation below. In the above code snippet, index: 0 would be the screen name "SetGame" below. index: 1 is "PlayGame" and index: 2 is "History". In my case I'm navigating back to index 0 which is "SetGame" and reseting routes/params/history in the navigation state object.

```
    <Tab.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Find"
  tabBarOptions={{
    tabStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#76B947',
      height: 90,
      paddingBottom: 30,
      margin: 0,
    },
    style: {
      height: 90,
    },
    activeTintColor: '#292929',
    inactiveTintColor: '#ededed',

  }}
>
  <Tab.Screen
    name="SetGame"
    component={SetGame}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
        <Feather name={'list'} size={25} color={color} />
      ),
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="PlayGame"
    component={PlayGame}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
        <Feather name={'play'} size={25} color={color} />
      ),
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="History"
    component={GameHistory}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
        <Feather name={'save'} size={25} color={color} />
      ),
    }}
  />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

In my app inside of the PlayGame component there is a function to goBackToSetGame. Meaning we want to reset our game which clears data in the database and resets navigation state. Essentially disabling the user to play a game until it gets set again.

```
    const goBackToSetGame = async () => {
    const gameInputs = {
      email: user.profile.email,
      players: [],
      holes: [],
      names: [],
      createdAt: Date.now(),
      gameStatus: "not-playing",
      scores: [{}]
    }

    await API.QuitGame(gameInputs).then((res) => {
      // reset scores state if the game is quit
      setScores(null);
      console.log("Changed gameStatus from server response: ", 
    res.data)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

    // reset props.navigation so you have to 
    // start a new game before coming back to this screen
    props.navigation.reset({
      index: 0,
      routes: [{name: "SetGame"}]
    });
 }
```

Comment: This looks interesting and useful. Can you maybe elaborate a bit? Where in the docs is it, and how/where it should be called?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had all screens in a Stack, therefore after I was done using the Route Params, I called **navigate()** to the same screen while explicitly setting all the params as null.