# React navigation params doesn't reset?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have filter screen and search screen. When user navigates from search screen I am passing search term from search screen to Home screen. Similarly I am doing samething for filter screen (passing filterOptions from filter screen to Home screen).

Now when I come from filter screen to home screen I want to set searchTerm to null and similarly if I am coming from search screen to home screen I want to set filterOptions to null how can I do that ?

In below code Line A and Line B doesn't set `filterOptions` and `searchTerm` to null thats why filter and search is not working because when filterOptions is not null I want searchTerm to be null that means only filter should work at that instance. Similarly if filterOptions is null then searchTerm must not be null that means only search should work at that instance.

Code:

```
filterProjectResults = (projects) => {

      let filterOptions = this.props.navigation.getParam('filterOptions', null);
      let searchTerm = this.props.navigation.getParam('searchTerm', null);

      console.log('Initial filterOptions ', filterOptions);  --> initially null
      console.log('intital searchTerm ', searchTerm); --> initially null


      if(filterOptions !== null){ 
        console.log('Inisde filter screen ', filterOptions)
        let display_filtered_projects = projects.filter((item) => item.floorplans.some(val => filterOptions.includes(val.bhk)));
        searchTerm = null;  <--- Line A
        return display_filtered_projects;

      } else if (searchTerm !== null) {
        console.log('Inside Search screen ', searchTerm);
        let search_filter_projects = projects.filter(
          (project) => {
            return project.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1
          }
        );
        filterOptions = null;   <<--- Line B
        return search_filter_projects;

      }

  }
```

search.js:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Projects', {searchTerm : this.state.text})}>
    <Image source={require('../../assets/images/search.png')} style={{width: 24, height: 24, resizeMode: 'contain'}}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

filter.js:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Projects', {filterOptions: this.state.filterOptions})}>
    <View style={styles.filterButton}>
        <Text style={styles.filterButtonText}>Apply Filters</Text>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I am passing this filtered or searched data inside Flatlist to display the results. If I try to implement it using state I get error -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4l1o.jpg code: https://gist.github.com/aditodkar/1df0175e2b13727daaae0373040f8dcf

Comment: where you're store searchTerm and filterOptions? in component state? what is Line A and B? is it variable or state?

Comment: @Dhaval I am not using state I am storing it inside variable. Check updated question.

Comment: then you should use state. then when filter apply at that time set state for search like this.setState({ searchTerm: null}) and vice versa for searchTerm.

Comment: @Dhaval But that gives me maximum state update exceeded error. I am calling filterProjectResults () inside render

Comment: @Dhaval Check updated question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59932246/6569224

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call

`this.props.navigation.navigate('Projects', {searchTerm : this.state.text})}>` 
can you also add `filterOptions: null` like this

`this.props.navigation.navigate('Projects', {searchTerm : this.state.text, filterOptions: null})}`?

And then for the other one you can call

`this.props.navigation.navigate('Projects', {searchTerm : this.state.text, searchTerm: null})}`

you can also call `this.props.navigation.setParams(params)` and set them to null whenever you want.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can update the params with navigation life cycle `on blur` when the screen is leaving event, also your params must is specified, because the params does shallow update instead of override the value

**search.js:**

```js
import {useFocusEffect} from '@react-navigation/native';
import React, {useCallback} from 'react';

useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      return () => {
        navigation.setParams({ searchTerm: null });
      };
    }, []),
);
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the right approach - calling setParams when the screen is unmounting leads to an error. As in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61371946/on-home-i-get-that-error-the-action-set-params-with-the-payload-paramsc and this git issue https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8547

Comment: @Yogesch it is completely different approach, your link reference is using React framework unmount event which is not manage by react navigation, but `useFocusEffect ` event is manage by react navigation, and if you read the comment in your git issue https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8547 , it also mentions to update params when the screen get `unfocus` (on blur even), not unmount from React

Answer (score 1):

This issue on github, [issue#6674](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6674), is the same question.

It's the default behaviour.