# Passing parameter and reset it when leave current screen by React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I try to pass a object type parameter from Home screen to the DailyActivity screen by touch the button that selected user Overlay in Home screen. But still showing last selected user's parameter data even though leave current(DailyActivity) to another screen.

So let me know these things..

1. How to reset parameter when move to another screen?
2. How to detect current screen name in child screen component?

**Home screen**

```
<Button
          buttonStyle={{ margin: 5, backgroundColor: "#ef9a9a" }}
          title="Daily Activity"
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.navigate("Daily Activity", { baby });
            setIsOverlayed(!isOverlayed);
          }}
        />
```

**DailyActivity Screen**

```
export default function DailyActivity({ route }) {
  if ({ route }) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Daily Activity Screen</Text>
        <Text>{route.params.baby.firstName}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Daily Activity Screen</Text>
        <Text>params not exist</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

 useFocusEffect(
      React.useCallback(() => {
        // Do something when the screen is focused

        return () => {
          // Do something when the screen is unfocused
          navigation.setParams({ contactId: null }) // reset parametr that you need
        };
      }, [setParams]),
    );
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the right approach - calling setParams when the screen is unmounting leads to an error. As in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61371946/on-home-i-get-that-error-the-action-set-params-with-the-payload-paramsc and this git issue https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8547

Answer (score 1):

do like this

In Home screen:

```
navigation.navigate("Daily Activity", { baby:baby });
setIsOverlayed(!isOverlayed);
```

and in daily activity screen make it as null after getting baby name

```
navigation.setParams({baby: null});
```

If you are using hooks then call this method

```
import {useIsFocused} from '@react-navigation/native';

const isFocused = useIsFocused();
export default function DailyActivity {
   useEffect(() => {
     !isFocused && resetNavigationMethod();
 }, [isFocused]);

  ... your codes
}
```

useIsFocused is used to whenever you are tried to changing screens, this this function will trigger. If you are going back, then isFocused will return as false.

Comment: the core question is how to reset the passed parameter when leave Daily Activity screen, so I need how to define statement like If Else statement. :) . So in the case, need to add some global state management?

Comment: I think if I get the current route name then it can be solution :)